# Unable to get payment gateway iframe to redirect outside of iframe

Tags: iframe, header, location, parent, payment

Before I start, allow me to give you some context. On my site I've got an iframe in my payment gateway that does the whole 3D Secure thing to verify the payment details but when it is done it redirects to my order confirmation page inside the iframe. Needless to say that would be a bit of an odd thing to see after making a payment.

My first process was to search through the gateway's files for the code that was redirecting it and adding some sort of _parent attribute unfortunately though the code that I believe does the redirect is a php header('location') string and I'm not sure how to go about telling that to open the link within the parent. I've done a bit of research and found that most people think the best solution would be to echo out the url with javascript but I'm not 100% of the best way to go about doing that and as it's a payment gateway I thought it would be best to get some advise rather than risk messing it up.

Here is the code in question that I believe does the redirect:

```
    function redirectBrowser($url) {

    $protocol = 'http://';

    if (getenv('HTTPS') == 'on'){
        $protocol = 'https://';
    }

    $url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.$url;
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.